# comment in .info file of Drupal

Tags: drupal, comments, file-type

how to put lines inside comment in

**.info file type.**

Does it differ if file used in Drupal? I found these files generally found in Drupal.

Comment: I found it is #. Any other way?

Comment: That link has nothing to do with Drupal's info files.

Comment: Update: Drupal 8 is slated to use YAML instead of the Drupal-specific .info file format.

YAML uses # comments (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the semicolon:

```
; This is a comment
```

Answer (score 5):

The character used as comment delimiter is reported in [Writing .info files (Drupal 6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/231036):

> info files may contain comments. The comment character is the **semi-colon** and denotes a comment at the beginning of a line. CVS Ids used to be placed at the head of info files using a semicolon, but now that Drupal.org has moved to git they are no longer included.

The equivalent book page for Drupal 7 ([Writing .info files (Drupal 7.x)](http://drupal.org/node/542202)) reports the following sentence:

> info files may contain comments. A **semi-colon** [;] placed at the beginning of a line makes that line a comment, and that line will not be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 info files extension is **.info**

> ; commented line

Similarly, for Drupal 8 info files extension is **.info.yml**

> # commented line